# Solving a simple partial differential equation.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, differential-topology

I'm trying to find every continuously differentiable functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $$\alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)+\beta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0 $$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are constants.

By inspection I can find a family of solution namely $f_c(x,y) = c(\beta x -\alpha y)$ for $c\in \mathbb{R}$ but I don't know that this is all of them, nor how I'd go about proving that it is (if it is) or finding all of them if it isn't. This is part of some practice sheet I have for a topology class, and this is in the section on the local inversion theorem and global inversion theorem, so I'm guessing it somehow involves this theorem but I don't know how. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Is $c$ meant to denote a constant or a function?

Comment: @AHusain it’s meant to be a constant, I’ll had the clarification to the post.

Comment: What happens if you say it is a function of one variable instead? So the parentheses means where you are evaluating the function $c$ instead of meaning multiplication.

Comment: A constant function is also a solution

Comment: @AHusain Oh yeah for any differentiable function $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ $f_c(x,y) = c(\beta x - \alpha y)$ still works as a solution, and I'm guessing this is all the solutions.. and the $\beta x- \alpha y$ is a change of variable or something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along a line written parametrically as $x = x_0 + \alpha t$, $y = y_0 + \beta t$, by the chain rule $$ \dfrac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \dfrac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \dfrac{dy}{dt} = \alpha \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \beta \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$
which means $f$ is constant along such a line.  Such a line can also be written implicitly
as $$\beta x - \alpha y = \text{constant}$$
where the "constant" will be different for each line.  So the general solution is $$f(x,y) = g(\beta x - \alpha y)$$
where $g$ is an arbitrary differentiable function.